# Uniform Convergence of Dirichlet Series over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n^x}$:

> Prove: if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n^s}$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n^x}$ uniform converges in $[s,\infty)$

My Proof:

For all $x\in [s,\infty)$: $\space$
We can write $\frac{a_n}{n^x}=\frac{a_n}{n^s}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{x-s}}$ and apply Abel's uniform convergence test.

$\frac{1}{n^{x-s}}$ monotonically decreasing and uniformly bounded.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n^s}$ uniform converges as it's a series of numbers that converges (given).

$\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n^x}$ uniform converges in $[s,\infty)$

Please help me validate this proof. Is it correct? Is it possible to use Abel's test in an interval with infinite endpoint?